# INSERT INTO ON UPDATE everything

Tags: mysql

I use this sql statement...

```
INSERT INTO users(id, email, phone, name )
 VALUES ($id, $email, $phone, $name)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE email=VALUES(email), phone=VALUES(phone), name=VALUES(name)
```

It works okey but: Is there a way to update every column without that column=VALUES(column) for every column?

Answer (score 2):

According to the [reference manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert-on-duplicate.html), explicitly listing each column is the only way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

If columns are using derived values (eg `foo=concat("one","two")`) then you don't use the VALUES function. Otherwise, yes. It just refers to what is passed in originally.

Read about it [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html).

Answer (score 0):

No, I don't think so. We need to always specify column name with there value from which we want to update.
Like this:

```
INSERT [LOW_PRIORITY | DELAYED | HIGH_PRIORITY] [IGNORE]
    [INTO] tbl_name [(col_name,...)]
    {VALUES | VALUE} ({expr | DEFAULT},...),(...),...
    [ ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
      col_name=expr
        [, col_name=expr] ... ]
```